# graphs in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Is anyone familiar with the graphs and charts availability in javaFX?
I know how to create a bar graph but I have some doubts..

I'm creating a bar graph with the tutorial provided by Oracle, but it is taking the values on y-axis that are provided in the program itself. So every time you run it, it'll display a graph with the same set of values.

But what I want is the graph should be able to read the values from a table in Ms access and then display the graph according to the values from table ,so that every time I run it, it'll be showing the values currently in the database.
 
Is it possible?

Please let me know if there's a way of achieving this. There must be a way else what's the point of having these graphs and charts in javaFX if they're only going to take static values.

Please let me know..
Thanks..

Scenario
I have a table in ms access with 2 columns "blood group" and "no.of units". 
see now the no of units in a blood bank keeps varying when a patient reuires some units of a blood group or when a hospital adds up units to it's blood bank. 
so what i want is that graph should be able to read the "no.of units " from the table and display the level of each blood group accordingly.so even when the column "no of units" gets modified due to certain operation when i click on a button it should be able to display the graph with the current values of each blood group from the table.. 
Now can you tell how should i do it ?? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you just wanted to know if its is possible. Yes you can do it !

Comment: i also want to know how can i do it..

Answer (score 0):

You must have used the following site to go through the documentation on *BARCHART IN JAVAFX*

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

Over here, when we are filling `series1`, using `series1.getData().add()`, instead of passing hardcoded values, you can pass the values that you have fetched from the `database`.

You can do the same thing for `series2`, `series3`.. As many series as you want to make ! Hope things are clear for you, or feel free to comment ! :)

-AA

Comment: Yes i used the same
preparedStatement ps=con.prepare("select * from <table_name>") 
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(); 
while(rs.next) 
{ // what should i write here
}
// rs.getInt(2)-will fetch me the value
now what should i write to add it to the graph.

Comment: You can add the values from resultSet into a List/ObservableList and then parse the List and add then to the series